# Showing all tags in admin -> edit post

Tags: tags

Someone knows how to show 'all tags' insteads of the 'most used tags' in edit post of administration panel?
This should give the ability to select with a single click tags that are not yet used!

Here is a screenshot of what I mean: [screenshot](http://www.meliusabundare.com/show-all-tags.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Ok, I've resolved in this manner:
go to wp-admin -> include and open ajax-actions.php file, inside wp_ajax_get_tagcloud function edit line 658, that shows as this:

```
$tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'number' => 45, 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

and change it with this:

```
$tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'number' => 45, 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC', 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
```

this will work for me; hope could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Never modify Wordpress core files!

Use your template's functions.php. You can check examples here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198778/69451

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code I wrote to modify the way tags are displayed. All tags are displayed by default, and the manual add tag box, as well as "Choose from the most used tags" text, are hidden. The implementation is a bit clunky, but it works well and doesn't involve editing core files.

Add this code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function example_wpadmin_show_all_tags( $args ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'get-tagcloud' )
        unset( $args['number'] );
        $args['hide_empty'] = 0;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'example_wpadmin_show_all_tags' );
function example_wpadmin_custom_css() {
    echo '<script>
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery("body.wp-admin #tagsdiv-post_tag #link-post_tag").trigger("click");
            jQuery("body.wp-admin #tagsdiv-post_tag #link-post_tag").hide();
        });
    </script>';
    echo '<style>
        body.wp-admin #tagsdiv-post_tag #link-post_tag{visibility:hidden;}
        body.wp-admin #tagsdiv-post_tag #post_tag .jaxtag{display:none;} //this line hides the manual add tag box - delete if not required
        body.wp-admin #tagsdiv-post_tag #tagcloud-post_tag a{display:block;} //this line puts each displayed tag on a new line - delete if not required
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'example_wpadmin_custom_css');
```

If you're using this with WooCommerce products instead of standard posts, just replace all instances of "post_tag" with "product_tag". I assume the same applies for all custom post types, but I've only tested it with posts and products.

Answer (score -1):

As of the current version, the file in question appears to be "ajax-actions.php" and is located in wp-admin/includes.

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. You will be able to leave [comments](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) when you gain some reputation on site.

Comment: I appreciate that, Rarst, but if I can't comment yet, how do I contribute this legitimate improvement to an existing answer? Seems odd to just have to sit on my hands. I realize I'm again probably breaking the rules by discussing something other than this page's topic here, so please advise me on where the appropriate place is to have that conversation. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that it feels discouraging, but answers are totally-not-a-good-thing-to-misuse. :) If you want to improve on existing answer you can suggest edit for it and it will be peer reviewed to be approved. In this specific case the original advice to edit core files is pretty horrible in a first place, so “right file to edit” is hardly saving it.

Comment: PS if you have more extensive question on how to use site you are always welcomed to ask on http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, Rarst. And true about editing core files - even though in this case I went ahead and did it, I realize it's absolutely not the way to go (in my case I don't mind if it reverts after a future update but obviously it is a Bad Way To Do It!) I'll check out the other discussion. Thanks again!

Answer (score -3):

Go to your WordPress installation and open `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. Search for a line that looks like

```
$tags = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'number' => 45, 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

and change the `45` to `999` or something like that ;-)

Then open `wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php` and modify the following line:

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#titlediv" class="tagcloud-link" id="link-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->choose_from_most_used; ?></a></p>
```

to

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js"><a href="#titlediv" class="tagcloud-link" id="link-<?php echo $tax_name; ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->labels->all_items; ?></a></p>
```

That's it, hope that helps...

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer.
I've just found another way to fix it.