# Show all post tags on post edit screen/sidebox

Tags: wp-admin, tags

I am looking for a way to show all post tags on post edit screen/tags sidebox in WordPress admin section. By default WordPress shows 45 most used tags but I need a way to list all tags there or at least increase this limit.

I found similar question here [Showing all tags in admin -> edit post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64058/). But it suggests to edit/modify WordPress core files which is not what I really want. Because upgrading WordPress will be a huge problem then.

I also could not find anything in Google search. So is there are way to list all or more than 45 tags on post edit page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say the easiest way to do it is use the `get_terms_args` filter and unset the `number` limit if the context is right (the AJAX request to get the tag cloud):

```
function wpse_64058_all_tags ( $args ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'get-tagcloud' )
        unset( $args['number'] );
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'get_terms_args', 'wpse_64058_all_tags' );
```

Note: In the edit box the link will still read "Choose from the most used tags", even though we're now displaying all of them.

Edit: As @bonger suggested, you *could* determine the post type from the referer:

```
if ( $qs = parse_url( wp_get_referer(), PHP_URL_QUERY ) ) {
    parse_str( $qs, $args );

    if ( ! empty( $args['post_type'] ) )
        $post_type = $args['post_type'];
    elseif ( ! empty( $args['post'] ) )
        $post_type = get_post_type( $args['post'] );
    else
        $post_type = 'post';
}
```

Comment: +1. Would be nice if it can be run only for specific post types, but I'm afraid is not so easy. Regarding *"Choose from the most used tags"*, is possible to use `gettext` filter to change it.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, we can change text. But I am okay with "Choose from the most used tags". Although I am wondering why can we not check for `post type` here? Is this executed before everything else.

Comment: There is no way to determine the post type within the context the filter executes. You *could* see which post type the taxonomy is attached to, but that's only useful if it's the *only* post type. The only other option is to remove the default `post_tags_meta_box` handler and replace it with your own.

Comment: Though you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to find out the `post_type` if you really wanted to.

Comment: @bonger Tru dat.

Comment: You could use [`wp_get_referer()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_referer/). Keep in mind that it returns `false` as well in the case if the current request and the previous are equal (whoever had that idea: slow clap).

Answer (score 0):

Addition to TheDeadMedic's answer, to show ALL tags:

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX && isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] === 'get-tagcloud' ) {
    unset( $args['number'] );
    $args['hide_empty'] = 0;
}
return $args;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some basic relevant info:

When setting a taxonomy setting to `'hierarchical'=>true` it will use the category format side box and will show all terms by default.